# Dump and load MSSQL Production Database to local machine with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, server, dump

I'd like to dump production **MSSQL DB** and load it to local machine. I tried several tools **gem 'yaml_db'**, **gem 'dump'** , but these tools don't work with **foreign keys** properly. In the end, I could hardcode the tables sequence to dump, and that works. But I am curious is there a proper way to make clear dump and load the db?

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `BACKUP DATABASE` and `RESTORE DATABASE`? Or are you trying to move from SQL Server to some other RDBMS?

Comment: Totally agree with @AlwaysLearning, there is no "Proper way" as any way you do it that works is "proper" it's just degrees of better or worse ways.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I don't have access of MS SQL Server, so I have only credentials of production db, and of course, ruby and rails :)

Comment: You should ask the server owner(s) for a backup. If it's data you should have access to for development purposes then they shouldn't have any problems providing you with a backup.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I know that. But I would like to do that using some gem or even command line.

Comment: I wrote a Rails engine to backup the production database and there's a Capistrano recipe to download the backup to your dev machine. I haven't looked at this in a while, but it's still working fine on the site that I developed it for. Take a look at https://github.com/lazylester/get_back, it may do what you need. On one site I used to get the backup emailed to me daily, automatically.